# Slowing down the moving circle in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I wanted to slow down the movement of the circle by giving it smaller y and x change like this:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            circleYchange = 0
            circleXchange = 0 
            circleYchange += 0.5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            circleYchange = 0
            circleXchange = 0 
            circleXchange += 0.5
```

and then adding that to the circleY and circleX, and drawing the circle:

```
circleX += circleXchange
circleY += circleYchange
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (circleX, circleY), size)
```

but it geve me this kind of error:

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

how do i slow down the movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *center* argument of [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) has to be a tuple with 2 integral components. You have to [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinate to integral values:

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (round(circleX), round(circleY)), size)
```